# Почему dataProvider в TestNG возвращает двумерный массив?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, тестирование, testng, автоматизация

Почему методы, помеченные аннотацией `@DataProvider` в TestNG возвращает двумерный массив `Object[][]`? Что там находится помимо значения параметра тестируемого метода?

В частности, почему в примере нужно передавать значение параметра в отдельном массиве? Почему нельзя было вернуть просто массив значений параметра?

```
publuc class SameClassDataProvider

{

     @DataProvider(name="data-provider")

     public Object[][] dataProviderMethod() {

     return new Object[][] { { "data one" }, { "data two" } };

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для метода с n параметрами `DataProvider` должен возвратить один или несколько массивов из n объектов. Каждый из этих объектов будет присвоен соответствующему параметру. Метод будет  вызван ровно столько раз, сколько наборов параметров в массиве.

Пример из [документации](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)

```
//This method will provide data to any test method that declares that its Data Provider
//is named "test1"
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public Object[][] createData1() {
 return new Object[][] {
   { "Cedric", new Integer(36) },
   { "Anne", new Integer(37)},
 };
}
 
//This test method declares that its data should be supplied by the Data Provider
//named "test1"
@Test(dataProvider = "test1")
public void verifyData1(String n1, Integer n2) {
 System.out.println(n1 + " " + n2);
}
```

У функции `verifyData1` два параметра, типа `String` и типа `Integer`. Соответственно, для тестирования этого метода нужно представить набор массивов, в котором первый элемент - строка, а второй элемент - число.

Провайдер данных в примере возвращает вот какой массив: `new Object[][] {{ "Cedric", new Integer(36) }, { "Anne", new Integer(37)}}`.

Соответственно, функция `verifyData1` будет вызвана два раза. Сначала как `verifyData1("Cedric", 36)`, второй раз как `verifyData1("Anne", 37)` (для наглядности я заменил объекты `Integer` на числовые литералы).